# Send vCards with PUSH notifications to iPhone, save them in Address Book

Tags: iphone, push-notification, vcf-vcard

I'm trying to wrap my head around this and see if it is possible to work.

Using the Apple PUSH server notifications, would it be possible to send a vcard, and make the application save it in the address book? If this is not possible, is there an alternative way this could be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I think you can do this.
Just send a push notification and use the userInfo part to tell the app about the VCard.
i don't kown if the userInfo can fit an full VCard, but you could all ways send some kind of ID with the push notification and just retrieve it from a server via the ID.

Then use ABPerson to insert the VCard: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html

I think you will have to parse the VCard your self.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Is it possible to do these types of 'heavier' operations (i.e. get access to the adress book API and save a contact) when receiving a push notification?

Comment: No, you app does not receive the notification, iOS does. Then the user can open the app via the notification or just ignore it.

Comment: If your app is open & your device receives a push, it will fire the - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo event. At this point, you can inspect the content of the push and act accordingly...